# Search only numbers with mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

i have project in ASP.NET MVC 3 and a mysql database that contains a table of string values for phone numbers (this phone numbers can be stored as 123 456-789 or 12345 6789 or 123456789 or any ways the user enter his number) and other table with a keywords data for that users.
The thing is that i have a search that will find in the keywords table (fulltext table) for the users, but i'm writing a method that search in the phone table if the search query matches against certain regular expression. 
I have 2 questions:
- How could be that regular expression from the C# code side that tells what method to execute (SearchByKeyword or SearchByNumber)?
- Using the same regular expression i think, i must do the mysql query to search in the phones table... how can i do it?

I hope i have explained well and sorry if my english is a little bit bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best when you capture the data to standardise the format it is saved in, IE:

```
111-111-1-111-11
1111-1111-1111
111111111111
1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
```

All will save as

```
111111111111
```

You can then do a simple LIKE query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblNumbers WHERE number LIKE '%111%'
```

Comment: There are tradeoffs though, what about cases where someone has an international phone number like +61 3 9898 1122, or they have an extension that you have to dial after the tone, like 1800-634-999 ext 895. If you strip all non-numbers when you save in the database you may loose important information.

Comment: @Haz best to normalise that data and store them in associated records.

Comment: The thing here is that i dont want to know the best way to storage the phones, i only want to know if i can do what i am asking for. Because i already have that logic, and i cant change it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that its bad idea to feed a phone number from the input -> directly to query variable.

better way would be:

```
input -> parser, error check procedure -> MySQL query request.
```

and before adding your phone number to the query - you can remove all extra symbols, like (, ), -, "space", etc.